# How to inject a property into a class that I don't control the creation of

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, property-injection

How do I inject the *IServiceManager* property into this class using autofac? This is a custom resource provider factory class that gets called when you make a call to `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("", "MyResource")` to get a resource string.

```
public class SqlResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
{
    // needs autofac property injection
    public IServiceManager ServiceManager { get; set; }

    public override IResourceProvider CreateGlobalResourceProvider(string classKey)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override IResourceProvider CreateLocalResourceProvider(string virtualPath)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static string GetAppRelativePath(string logicalPath)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this exact same problem - with an ASP.NET `ResourceProviderFactory` - and the answer is, unfortunately, that **you have to use service location**.

There's no "hook" into the pipeline anywhere that you can inject anything or change the built-in ASP.NET behavior. Thus, if you need something put into a property, it has to be set in the constructor.

```
public class SqlResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
{
  public IServiceManager ServiceManager { get; set; }

  public SqlResourceProviderFactory()
  {
    this.ServiceManager =
      DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IServiceManager>();
  }
}
```

Yeah, it's really ugly.

**Something very important to consider here, especially with respect to Autofac, is the lifetime scope for which your `IServiceManager` is registered.**

The `ResourceProviderFactory` is created once and cached. Same with the global/local resource providers that come out of the Create* methods. we had a heck of a time with this because it means there's not necessarily an `HttpContext` at the time the factories get created, and even if there is, if any of the downstream dependencies are registered `InstancePerHttpRequest` then they'll be disposed of and you're hosed.

- Anything used by your `ResourceProviderFactory` or generated resource providers - all the way down the stack - should be registered either `SingleInstance` or `InstancePerDependency`.
- If possible, instead of using `DependencyResolver.Current` (which, for Autofac, requires an active `HttpContext`), reference the application container directly. That means you need to store a reference to it somewhere else (a global static variable?) and use that.

This is what a more complete solution might involve:

```
// Create some "holder" for the app container.
public static class ApplicationContainerProvider
{
  public static ILifetimeScope Container { get; set; }
}


// In Global.asax, build your container and set it in both
// the DependencyResolver AND in the holder class.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Something>().As<ISomething>();
var container = builder.Build();
var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
ApplicationContainerProvider.Container = container;


// In your service location, reference the container instead of
// DependencyResolver.
public class SqlResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
{
  public IServiceManager ServiceManager { get; set; }

  public SqlResourceProviderFactory()
  {
    this.ServiceManager =
      ApplicationContainerProvider.Container.Resolve<IServiceManager>();
  }
}
```

Note that since you're resolving that out of the root container, it'll stick around for the lifetime of the application. Even if you register it as `InstancePerDependency`, because of the internal caching .NET does, it'll only get created once.

If you don't like creating your own static holder class like that, you can abstract it away by using the `CommonServiceLocator` and the `Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator` packages.

Comment: I was using service location already just to "squeak by" until I could find the correct DI approach, so it sucks that there is no way. I thought about a creating a custom ResourceManager to bypass .Net's built in version but its a lot of work, still debating. You've pointed out the issue of lifetime scope which I haven't even considered yet. I'm going to give this singleton container a shot and see how it goes. It just doesn't feel right holding onto a DbContext  instance for the duration of the application though.

Comment: Hi Travis, I'm running into all kinds of trouble trying this. Lots of `No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest'` messages and various others. I was thinking if I simply do this: `public IServiceManager ServiceManager {get{return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IServiceManager>();}}` that it will always go out and get a fresh IServiceManager for me right? Even if the SqlResourceProviderFactory is cached its always going to resolve the IServiceManager.

Comment: Those exceptions are why I mentioned you can't use DependencyResolver.Current - the AutofacDependencyResolver *requires* a web context and you probably won't have one when this gets created. And, again, *nothing* in the entire dependency chain for the service manager can be registered InstancePerHttpRequest.

Comment: And don't forget - you don't necessarily get a new resource manager every time. ASP.NET caches these things, even with a factory, so having a dynamic property like that won't help you. Truly, think of this like a singleton that gets resolved once for the whole app. You get one shot at creating them and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Ok, I guess my issue now is that I need two containers. A static one for special snowflakes like `ResourceProviderFactory` and another for the rest of the application that need InstancePerHttpRequest() scopes. I'll start a new question.